Kimball Model Design - When to Snow or Star
I have data model for a Kimball style data warehouse. Regarding the whole Star vs Snowflake schema conundrum when it comes to dimensional tables and their ownership.
Scenario: A bunch of IoT Devices records readings every few minutes. Each IoT devices belongs to a certain business entity (branch). Meaning that with row level security a user at certain Business Unit can only view data for a device that belongs to their Business Unit.
What would be the better model?
Option A - Snowflake
FactDeviceReading links to DimBusinessEntity via the link between DimBusinessEntity and DimDevice. In order to know which Business Entity the Device Readings belongs to one must look via DimDevice.

Option B - Star
A direct link between FactDeviceReading and DimBusinessEntity. While a "soft" relationship exist between DimBusinessEntity and DimDevice.

Open to suggestions.

I think one of the drivers for your design should be how you are implementing row-level security (RLS)
Keep your RLS model consistent. So if you are using DimBusinessEntity to drive your RLS then add the FK for this Dim to every fact table, rather than doing it via DimDevice as, presumably, not every fact table (now or in the future) can be guaranteed to include an FK to DimDevice
If you do this then there is no need to create an FK between DimBusinessEntity and DimDevice as they are always linked via a fact table.
If you are not using DimBusinessEntity to drive your RLS then I still wouldn't snowflake the Dims. If Business Entity only ever exists in the context of a device then consider denormalising the Business Entity attributes into the Device Dim
